# Coloring a 3×n board using 3 colors - Understanding Help

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Im trying to solve this question also found a solution. [Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215805/coloring-a-3-times-n-board-using-3-colors?newreg=431839d877ee470187593ce2689efde3) But could not understand it.

> Find the total number of ways a 3×n board can be painted using 3 colors while making sure no cells of the same row or the same column have entirely the same color. The answer must be computed modulo 109+7.

While I understand how total ways are 24^n but couldn't understand how rest of the terms are calculated. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have this question for exam tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Please guys can anyone help me :(

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215805/coloring-a-3-times-n-board-using-3-colors?noredirect=1&lq=1